# Run query in Linux for selecting CSV'S

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

In the Linux:

there are many .csvs' in the folder, I have to select those csv's file having column name {'PREDICT' = 646}.

check this link:
https://prnt.sc/gone85

what kind of query works?

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373885/searching-a-csv-file-using-grep

Comment: You want to run the code to find in multiple files? I would like to request you to mention more clear details in your post so please help us to help you, enjoy learning !!

Comment: what do you mean with *to **select** those csv's*?

Answer (score 1):

Providing test data which was unprovided ):

```
$ cat > file1
ACTUAL PREDICT
1 2
3 646

$ cat > file2
ACTUAL PREDICT
1 2
3 666
```

Then some GNU awk (`nextfile`) *to select those csv's file having column name {'PREDICT' = 646}* or where there is column `PREDICT` with a value `646`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="PREDICT")p=i}$p==646{print FILENAME;nextfile}' file1 file2
file1
```

Explained:

```
awk '
FNR==1 {                   # get the column number of PREDICT column for each file
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if($i=="PREDICT")
            p=i            # set it to p
}
$p==646 {                  # if p==646, we have a match
    print FILENAME         # print the filename
    nextfile               # and move on to the next file
}' file1 file2             # all the candicate files
```

Answer (score 0):

gnu **awk** solution without loop:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{FS=","}
FNR==1 && s=substr($0,1,index($0,"PREDICT")) { # look for index of PREDICT
   i=sub(/,/, "", s) + 1                       # and count nr of times you
                                               # can replace "," in preceding
                                               # substring
}
s && $i==646 { print FILENAME; nextfile }
```

some input:

```
$ cat file1.csv
ACTUAL,PREDICT,COUNTRY,REGION,DIVISION,PRODUCTTYPE,PRODUCT,QUARTER,YEAR,MONTH
925,850,CANADA,EAST,EDUCATION,FURNITURE,SOFA,1,1993,12054
925,533,CANADA,EAST,EDUCATION,FURNITURE,SOFA,1,1993,12054
925,646,CANADA,EAST,EDUCATION,FURNITURE,SOFA,1,1993,12054

$ cat file2.csv
ACTUAL,PREDICT,COUNTRY,REGION,DIVISION,PRODUCTTYPE,PRODUCT,QUARTER,YEAR,MONTH
925,850,CANADA,EAST,EDUCATION,FURNITURE,SOFA,1,1993,12054
925,533,CANADA,EAST,EDUCATION,FURNITURE,SOFA,1,1993,12054
925,111,CANADA,EAST,EDUCATION,FURNITURE,SOFA,1,1993,12054
```

and:

```
$ cp file1.csv file3.csv
```

gives:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk *.csv
file1.csv
file3.csv
```

Or use a one-liner:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==1 && s=substr($0,1,index($0,"PREDICT")) {i=sub(/,/, "", s) + 1}s && $i==646 { print FILENAME; nextfile }' *.csv
file1.csv
file3.csv
```