# Using the cmd argument in fread() to conditionally load a large data set

Tags: r, cmd, grep, data.table, fread

I'm working with a .csv file that ~15 GB, and I'm looking for a robust way to conditionally load the data. I found that I can do something of the sort by using the `fread(cmd,...)` argument to preprocess the data before loading it.

My approach was to identify `subject_id`'s of interest as an object (i.e., `ids_to_select`), and then pass that object into a grep cmd. Below I have some sample code of loading a dataset based on grep'ing the values within `ids_to_select`

I noticed that I did indeed obtain rows for those `subject_id%in%c("001","002")`, but I also obtained extra rows because there was a grep match for the `labevent_id` column. I can easily subset this dataset via `DT_subset <- DT_subset[subject_id%in%ids_to_select]` to get rid of the extra rows, but wanted to know if there's a way to:

1. Specify in the `fread(cmd,...)` that I want to select rows based on values of a certain column (e.g., use the grep command to search for values only the `subject_id` column)
2. If 1. above is possible, will it also be possible to select rows based on two columns and grep different values for each column (e.g. grep specific values in `subject_id` and grep specific values in `itemid`)

Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated.

```
library(data.table)
`%+%` <- function(a,b) paste0(a,b)

DT <- data.table(subject_id=c(rep(c("001","002","003","004"),each=3)),
                 labevent_id=c(342,942,102,
                               400,401,403,
                               1001,1002,1003,
                               400,401,403),
                 itemid=c(1,2,3,
                          5,6,1,
                          4,1,2,
                          1,1,2))

fwrite(DT,file = "~/Desktop/DT.csv")

ids_to_select <- c("001","002")
DT_subset <- fread(cmd = "grep -E '"%+%paste0(ids_to_select,collapse = "|")%+%"' ~/Desktop/DT.csv")

names(DT_subset) <- names(DT)
DT_subset
```

```
   subject_id labevent_id itemid
1:          1         342      1
2:          1         942      2
3:          1         102      3
4:          2         400      5
5:          2         401      6
6:          2         403      1
7:          3        1001      4
8:          3        1002      1
```

Comment: Just use something more feature rich than grep, or learn regexp enough to specify column separators inside the expression. Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373885/searching-a-csv-file-using-grep

Comment: If the only issue is that it's not reading from the first column you can add `^` (so it searches only at the beginning of the line): `fread(cmd = 'grep -E "^001|^002" DT.csv')`